# How to get field from Map object

Tags: java, apex-code

I'm little confused trying to access a field in this object, could you help me?

I have the following sentence in the code:

Map<String, Object> tester = exampleFunction();

When I get the response in system.debug(tester) I get the following structure:

```
{option=222222XX, 
message=(messages:[subOption1=Test1, 
subOption2=Test2])
}
```

What I am trying to access is the value of "suboption2", how can I do this? whats the name of this type of structure?

thank you in advance

Comment: You need to use get - https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-get-method-in-java-with-examples/amp/

Comment: I already tried to use the get, when I try tester.get('message') it returns the (messages:[subOption1=Test1, 
subOption2=Test2])
when I try tester.get('subOption2') I get undefined

Comment: The function is clearly returning a map that maps keys (strings) to objects, which in your case seems to be an array/list. Youll have ro either change the function to build a map of String <-> String. Or access the list and understand in which index is the desired value. It also seems like your list holds strings that youll need tomparse. Please post what the function exampleFumction does. How does it builds the map

Comment: the problem is that I dont have access to the function code (its a hidden code in salesforce) but I always have the same structure in the response, in this example it would be the [1] array element inside the "messages" structure, is there a way to get this? like tester.get('message').get('messages')[1]   //sorry Im learning

Comment: Yes indeed. Then youll have another map object. Do something  like tester.get(“message”).get(“messages”)[1].get(“subOption2”).  Id suggest to try and create such map yourself and access it on some playground https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php